# extending a list to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am trying to extend values to a list if an element in `List1` equals an item in `List2`. I am using extend instead of append because extend is suppose to merge two lists. Instead it seems to be nesting lists.

Removing the brackets around `y[1],y[2]` yields:

`SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`

```
List1 = [['value1','value2','Value3'],['value4','value5','value6']]
List2 = [['option1','option2','value2'],['option3','option4','value5']]

for x in List1:
    x.extend([y[1],y[2]] for y in List2 if y[2] == x[1])
print List1
```

My output:

```
[['value1', 'value2', 'Value3', ['option2', 'value2']], ['value4', 'value5', 'value6', ['option4', 'value5']]]
```

Desired output:

```
[['value1', 'value2', 'Value3', 'option2', 'value2'], ['value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'option4', 'value5']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `[[y[1],y[2]] for y in List2 if y[2] == x[1]]` return list of list

```
>>> List1 = [['value1','value2','Value3'],['value4','value5','value6']]
>>> List2 = [['option1','option2','value2'],['option3','option4','value5']]
>>> for x in List1:
...    [[y[1],y[2]] for y in List2 if y[2] == x[1]]
... 
[['option2', 'value2']]
[['option4', 'value5']]
```

so get first item from the list to extend in `x`

```
>>> List1 = [['value1','value2','Value3'],['value4','value5','value6']]
>>> List2 = [['option1','option2','value2'],['option3','option4','value5']]
>>> for x in List1:
...     x.extend([[y[1],y[2]] for y in List2 if y[2] == x[1]][0])
... 
>>> List1
[['value1', 'value2', 'Value3', 'option2', 'value2'], ['value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'option4', 'value5']]
>>>
```

---

Python beginner 
Extended above code line by line.

1. Used for loop to iterate items from the List1 and List2
2. If condition to check values.
3. Use list extend method to append list items into existing list.

code:

```
>>> List1 = [['value1','value2','Value3'],['value4','value5','value6']]
>>> List2 = [['option1','option2','value2'],['option3','option4','value5']]
>>> 
>>> for x in List1:
...     for y in List2:
...             if y[2]==x[1]:
...                     print "In if value:", [y[1],y[2]]
...                     x.extend([y[1],y[2]])
... 
In if value: ['option2', 'value2']
In if value: ['option4', 'value5']
>>> List1
[['value1', 'value2', 'Value3', 'option2', 'value2'], ['value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'option4', 'value5']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the iterator/list of iterators/lists to a iterator/list which then can be passed to `.extend(`. This will work in the case that:

```
([y[1],y[2]] for y in List2 if y[2] == x[1])
```

Has any number of matches. The example input only has one but it is better to expect more as reasonable. See:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> List1 = [['value1','value2','Value3'],['value4','value5','value6']]
>>> List2 = [['option1','option2','value2'],['option3','option4','value5']]
>>> 
>>> for x in List1:
...     x.extend(itertools.chain.from_iterable([y[1],y[2]] for y in List2 if y[2] == x[1]))
... 
>>> print List1
[['value1', 'value2', 'Value3', 'option2', 'value2'], ['value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'option4', 'value5']]
```